# Three postgres with other dbname in gitlab service

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to write e2e tests, the doc says https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#available-settings-for-services that each service can have its own variables, but my runner doesn't have this functionality yet, because i have other version

so, this code is work

```
test-e2e:
  image: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/golang/go:1.18
  services:
    - name: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/docker/postgres:latest
      alias: db
    - name: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/docker/postgres:latest
      alias: db-1
    - name: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/docker/postgres:latest
      alias: db-2
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: database
    POSTGRES_USER: database
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: database
```

but i want have database with other dbnames, this code don't work

```
test-e2e:
  image: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/golang/go:1.18
  services:
    - name: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/docker/postgres:latest
      alias: db
      variables:
         POSTGRES_DB: database
         POSTGRES_USER: database
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: database
    - name: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/docker/postgres:latest
      alias: db-1
      variables:
         POSTGRES_DB: database-1
         POSTGRES_USER: database
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: database
    - name: gitlab-registry.xx.ru/docker/postgres:latest
      alias: db-2
      variables:
         POSTGRES_DB: database-2
         POSTGRES_USER: database
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: database
```

is it possible to pass POSTGRES_DB through `command` or `entrypoint`?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in gitlab, I redid the tests on dind